# What is the minimal steps to setup a client-server network using Windows Server 2008 R2 standard?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

### Background

I have

- One computer server with Win Server 2008 R2 standard installed but it has not been configured. This server has 2 LAN adapters. One adapter is connected to ISP and the other one connected to HUB/Switch.
- Other computers working as clients are connected to the same HUB/Switch to which the server is connected.
- IP Printers, IP scanners, IP camera are also connected to the same HUB/Switch.

Note: I am a newbie. I only know how to plug RJ-45 sockets and assembly computer peripherals.
I have no prior experience in Windows Server at all. Please teach me from the newbie's point of view.

### Objective

I want to establish the following:

1. Each client can access the internet, printers, scanners after it has been successfully authenticated by the server. Unauthenticated clients cannot access the internet, printers, etc.
2. The server hosts a local site. Clients can browse internally using a private domain www.company.com. If the same domain name has been used by other on the internet, my private domain must override the public domain.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want centralised user and computer account management, I suggest you look at setting up Active Directory (AD). You would do this by promoting the Windows 2008 Server to a domain controller. The AD accounts can then be use to control access to network resources.
2. This is usually achieved by setting up an internal DNS server (which is required for AD).

Comment: Good suggestion. It'll definitely be a big task for a newbie!